# How can I inspect if an element inside a cell is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The function "insert()" makes table cells that contain task names given by input. Every task name has a checkbox appended and how can I inspect if an element in a cell is checked so I can change its properties? I want the function "completeTasks()" to check for a checked element so when I press the button that calls the function, elements that are checked should be green and strikethrough(line-through).

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    Task Name: <input type="text" id="name">

    <button id="ins" onclick="insert()">Insert</button>

    <table id="tabl3">

    </table>

    <button id="comp" onclick="completeTasks()">Complete Tasks</button>
    <button id="del" onclick="deleteTasks()">Delete Tasks</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var i=0;
            var r=0;
            var arrName = [];

        function insert()
        {
            var chk = document.createElement("input");
            chk.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            arrName[i] = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var table = document.getElementById("tabl3");

            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            r++;// counting the rows so i can delete them all later if i want to

            cell1.innerHTML = arrName[i];
            cell1.appendChild(chk); // appending a checkbox to the element so i can check it later
            i++;
        }

        function completeTasks(){
        // if one or more elements are checked when clicking this button
        // then the checked task name(s) would have green color and have a line-through text decoration.
        //.style.color = "green";
        //.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        }

        function deleteTasks(){
        // will probably have to delete all the cells so i did it like this
        for(let c = 0; c<r; c++){
        document.getElementById("tabl3").deleteRow(0);
    }
        }
    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll('#tabl3 [type=checkbox]').forEach(cb => { ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first target all the checked check box using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then loop through them and set the style to the closest *td* element.

**Demo:**

```html
Task Name: <input type="text" id="name">

<button id="ins" onclick="insert()">Insert</button>

<table id="tabl3">

</table>

<button id="comp" onclick="completeTasks()">Complete Tasks</button>
<button id="del" onclick="deleteTasks()">Delete Tasks</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var i=0;
  var r=0;
  var arrName = [];

  function insert()
  {
      var chk = document.createElement("input");
      chk.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
      arrName[i] = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var table = document.getElementById("tabl3");

      var row = table.insertRow(0);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      r++;// counting the rows so i can delete them all later if i want to

      cell1.innerHTML = arrName[i];
      cell1.appendChild(chk); // appending a checkbox to the element so i can check it later
      i++;
  }

  function completeTasks(){

    var checkedEl = document.querySelectorAll('#tabl3 input:checked'); // get all the checked checkbox inside the table
    checkedEl.forEach(function(el){ //loop through them
      el.closest('td').style.color = "green";
      el.closest('td').style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    });


  }

  function deleteTasks(){
    // will probably have to delete all the cells so i did it like this
    for(let c = 0; c<r; c++){
      document.getElementById("tabl3").deleteRow(0);
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you, kind sir. I honestly don't know much about this "querySelectorAll" so I'm gonna have to educate myself more.

Comment: @KhishigdelgerGanbold, you are most welcome, you can refer the link provide in the updated answer:)